# Bootstrap 3, overwrite btn.active, click event is disapear 1px after element in anchor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I've got a code as this one

```
<a class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Button Name</span></a>
```

I use btn.active with

```
btn.active{
 position:relative;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
}
```

to add some nice click effect to my buttons, but there is a strange thing, 1px after any element which is in the .btn element is as disabled it is not clickable. You can see in http://jsfiddle.net/44cAy/1/

Right after the black border in that button, when click the event is not triggered.  Why is happening this and Is there a way to be fixed? Sorry if there are any mistakes in my English I work on that :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what browser? I am click in chrome all area is clickable.

Comment: Couldnt find the deadpixel, looks normal to me, which browser you are using?

Comment: Mozilla all right. Or i am don't undrstand what the problem?

Comment: Try give the button z-index: 9999999; may be in this is trouble.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in Firefox 28. If you click the top-left corner, the click event doesn't fire.

Comment: If you use a `<button>` element instead of an `<a>` element, it doesn't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Firefox 27.0.1, 1px after the span's black border, it is not clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this should work:

```
.btn:active:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

We are simple adding area to the area we "lose" by moving the element, if that makes sense.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44cAy/4/)